# How to parse the data into columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to parse the data into columns:
data given below:

```
 Header                      STREET CITY    STATE   ZIP PHONE
=====================================================================
BUSINESS ADDRESS:        |
STREET 1:300             |
CITY:FAIRPORT            |
STATE:NY                 |
ZIP:14450                |
BUSINESS PHONE:7263934130|                  
=====================================================================
```

I have tried by using split_part,But its not giving proper result.
How can I parse the data into columns.

Comment: Can you also state in your question what you have already tried?  I can already imagine there being a problem finding a suitable delimiter to separate columns.

Comment: what's your expected output ??

Comment: i have tried to the below query:

SELECT TRIM( SPLIT_PART(header, 
                                       'STREET1:',
                                        2
                                      ) , 
                             E'\t'
                           ) AS STREET1 
FROM TAB1;

Comment: @user2803461 Please edit your question with the complete table structure and expected output

Comment: @user2803461 how actually your data looks like  ??

Comment: `E'\t'` is a tab character. Your data looks like it's using a newline `\n` or a CR/LF `\r\n` to separate the elements

Comment: @user2803461 does `BUSINESS ADDRESS:
STREET 1:300
CITY:FAIRPORT
STATE:NY
ZIP:14450 
BUSINESS PHONE:7263934130` is in a single row or each of them are in seperate rows ?

Comment: Is that horrible "BUSINESS ADDRESS: STREET 1:300 CITY:FAIRPORT STATE:NY ZIP:14450 BUSINESS PHONE:7263934130" already in the database? If not, split it up before inserting. If its already there, well, at least you've learned not to store data as : separated items again...